# Can't import java jar file into STS Grails project

Tags: grails, groovy, jar

I have built a new basic grails project. I have a basic java object I've written outside of grails, and jarred up. I've added the jar file to the grails project, via  the **`properties > Java build path > Libraries tab > Add Jars`**.

Then I try to access it in a grails controller, and get a *class def not found error*.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**TestController.groovy**

```
package testproject

import test.TestClass

class TestController {
    def index() { 
        def testClass = new TestClass()
        render 'Index page'
    }
}
```

and:

in the jar, **TestClass.java**

```
package test;

public class TestClass {
    private String string;

    public void setString(String string)
    {
        this.string = string;
    }

    public String getString()
    {
        return string;
    }
}
```

---

The error is:

> C:\Users\One\TestProject\grails-app\controllers\testproject\TestController.groov
>   y: 3: unable to resolve class test.TestClass @ line 3, column 1.
>   import test.TestClass

Answer (score 4):

The STS classpath generated from the Grails classpath, but it's unidirectional. Adding items in STS has no effect on Grails.

Put the jar file in your lib directory and run `grails compile --refresh-dependencies`. Then re-sync STS from Grails by right-clicking the project node in the tree and running Grails Tools | Refresh Dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to import it in the Grails controller.

```
import your.java.ClassName
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have included that I did that, yes.

Comment: Can you update your question with the controller source and the full StackTrace of the error?

Comment: just added the code, and the error I get is C:\Users\Joe\TestProject\grails-app\controllers\testproject\TestController.groov
y: 3: unable to resolve class test.TestClass
 @ line 3, column 1.
   import test.TestClass